# Using separate to split uneven number of variables in a column

Tags: r, split, tidyr

I have data like this:

```
x <- c("France:4|Morroco:8|Italy:2", "Scotland:6|Mexico:2", "Scotland:2")
> player_country_info <- data.frame(x)
> setnames(player_country_info, "player_country_data")
> names(player_country_info)
[1] "player_country_data"
> is.data.frame(player_country_info)
[1] TRUE
> head(player_country_info)
                country_data
1 France:4|Morocco:8|Italy:2
2        Scotland:6|Mexico:2
3                 Scotland:2
```

I'd like an intermediary data frame that look like this:

```
player_country_data.1   player_country_data.2   player_country_data.3
France:4                Morocco:8               Italy:2
Scotland:6              Mexico:2                NA
Scotland:2              NA                      NA
```

I plan on then using the dplyr::separate function to separate the above to look like this, using this command for each column.

```
player_country_info %>% separate( col=player_country_data.1, into=c("country_name.1","player_count.1), sep=":")

country_name.1  player_count.1  country_name.2  player.2    country_name.3 player.3
France          4               Morocco         8           Italy           2
Scotland        6               Mexico          2
Scotland        2
```

Is there an more efficient way to do the above? Perhaps a command that does it in one step? Or should I process it with a for loop outside a while loop?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I had changed the df names but edited it above. I'm looking at cSplit but was hoping to do it all with dplyr::separate. Thanks

Comment: Is | a special character that I have do something like escape? Using cSplit doesn't seem to be splitting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `separate` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
country_info %>% 
  separate(country_data, 
           into = sprintf('%s.%s', rep(c('country','player.count'),3), rep(1:3, each=2)))
```

the result:

```
  country.1 player.count.1 country.2 player.count.2 country.3 player.count.3
1    France              4   Morroco              8     Italy              2
2  Scotland              6    Mexico              2      <NA>           <NA>
3  Scotland              2      <NA>           <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
```

Separate automatically recognizes `:` and `|` as characters on which it has to separate. If you want to separate on a specific character, you need to specify that with the `sep` argument. In this case you could use `sep = '[:|]'`. This also prevents misbehavior of the automatic detection when there are missing values (see discussion in the comments).

With `sprintf` you paste together the two vectors `rep(c('country','player.count'),3)` and `rep(1:3, each=2)` into a vector of column names where `%s.%s` tells `sprintf` to treat the two vectors are string-vectors and paste them together with a dot as separator. See `?sprintf` for more info. The `each` argument tells `rep` not to repete the whole vector a number of times, but to repete each element of the vector a number of times.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I was looking for. Could you kindly explain the logic of steps? Like I assume I need to know the maximum number of values to expect (3 in this case)? But what is the each=2 and sprint('%s.%s')?

Comment: @Jazzmine added an explanation

Comment: Thanks h3rm4n - One more question, what if I have row that is missing data like France:4|Morocco:|Italy:2  Where there is no value for Morocco?  I get this error Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  : 
  argument is of length zero. When trying what's in the following comment:

Comment: x <- c("France:4|Morocco:|Italy:2", "Scotland:6|Mexico:2", "Scotland:2")
player_country_info2 <- data.frame(x)
setnames(player_country_info2, "player_country_data")
names(player_country_info2)
is.data.frame(player_country_info2)

head(player_country_info2)

head(player_country_info2$player_country_data)
player_country_info2 %>% 
  separate(country_data, sprintf('%s.%s', rep(c('country','player.count'),3), rep(1:3, each=2)))

Comment: @Jazzmine specifying the separator with `sep = '[:|]'` solves this

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in a single step using `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(country_info, 'country_data', ':|\\|', fixed = FALSE)
```

If we need only the intermediate step

```
cSplit(country_info, 'country_data', '|')
```

---

Or using `tidyr`, we create the vector of column names in the expected output with `outer` and then specify the `into` columns with 'nm1' in the `separate`.

```
library(tidyr)
nm1 <- c(outer(c('country_name.', 'player_count.'), 1:3, FUN = paste0))
separate(country_info, country_data, into = nm1, sep="[:|]")
#  country_name.1 player_count.1 country_name.2 player_count.2 country_name.3 player_count.3
#1         France              4        Morroco              8          Italy              2
#2       Scotland              6         Mexico              2           <NA>           <NA>
#3       Scotland              2           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>
```

#### Update

With the new data showed by OP in the comments

```
separate(player_country_info2, player_country_data, into = nm1, sep="[:|]", convert= TRUE)
#  country_name.1 player_count.1 country_name.2 player_count.2 country_name.3 player_count.3
#1         France              4        Morocco             NA          Italy              2
#2       Scotland              6         Mexico              2           <NA>             NA
#3       Scotland              2           <NA>             NA           <NA>             NA
```

---

If this is about efficiency, another option is `tstrsplit` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(country_info)[, tstrsplit(country_data, '[:|]', type.convert = TRUE)], nm1)[]
#  country_name.1 player_count.1 country_name.2 player_count.2 country_name.3 player_count.3
#1:         France              4        Morroco              8          Italy              2
#2:       Scotland              6         Mexico              2             NA             NA
#3:       Scotland              2             NA             NA             NA             NA
```

Comment: This works as well, as I just tested it. Could you explain the use of  "[:|]". Is this how to handle | (pipes) as I was not getting separate to recognize the | . Thanks

Comment: Thanks Akrun for spending time on the update, yes it works even with missing values. I appreciate it.